# Поиск "скрытой" подстроки в строке

Tags: алгоритм, строки, поиск, подстрока

Надо узнать если ли в строке "раздробленная" подстрока.
Пример:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У нас имеется строка и предпологаемая подстрока, надо просто вывести true или false если такая трока имеется

Comment: Хорошо. Вам надо. Вопрос в чём?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов как написал в вопросе выше, нужно просто вывести булевое  значение если подстрока найдется

Comment: `true`. Вывел. SO не биржа фрилансеров. И Ваш вопрос, скорее всего, закроют, потому что `Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу`.

Comment: Я попрбовал простой naive algorithm, но как и думал время n^2 слишком медленное

Comment: Так укажите это в вопросе, потому что сейчас Ваш вопрос полностью подходит под пункт, который я Вам указал.

Comment: все-же там сработал простой цикл

Answer (score 3):

```
string a, b; cin >> a >> b;
int bIndex=0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    if (b[bIndex] == a[i]) {
        bIndex++;
    }
}

if (bIndex==b.size()) {
    cout << "YES";
} else {
    cout << "NO";
}
```

Comment: Вместо `bIndex++;` лучше сделать `if (++bIndex == b.size()) break;`

Comment: @Qwertiy разве тогда он не будет инкреминтироваться на каждой проверке

Comment: Так внутрь же. Заменить только то, что я написал, а не всё.