# Поиск подходящих выражений как это сделано в IDEA

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть набор предложений по типу "Green Apple", и каждое имеет от 2 до 7 слов. Нужно находить среди них к примеру "Green Apple" по таким ключевым словам как "gra" или "gap". Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вообще ничего непонятно.

Comment: @qwertiy Поиск классов в идее работает идеально. Можно вводить не зависимо от регистра он найдет набор всех классов которые подходят под искомое слово, по типу того что описал.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1014913/178988 - оно?

Comment: @Qwertiy чем тебе 3 варианта в этом ответе не нравятся? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, тут оптимальней использовать Trie. Например, есть класс

```
public class TrieNode {
    private HashMap<Character, TrieNode> _children = new HashMap<>();
    private String _payload = null;
}
```

Он хранит текущее слово и подузлы, где каждый подузел асоциирован с символом. Далее, напишем для класса функцию добавления слова

```
public void add(String str) {
    add(str, 0);
}

private void add(String str, int ind) {
    if (str.length() == ind) {
        _payload = str;
        return;
    }

    Character c = str.charAt(ind);
    c = Character.toLowerCase(c);

    if (_children.containsKey(c)) _children.get(c).add(str, ind + 1);
    else {
        TrieNode next = new TrieNode();
        _children.put(c, next);
        next.add(str, ind + 1);
    }
}
```

Функцию поиска по паттерну

```
public ArrayList<String> retrieve(String filter) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    retrieve(filter.toLowerCase(), 0, result);
    return result;
}

private void retrieve(String filter, int index, ArrayList<String> result) {
    if (index < filter.length()) {
        Character current = filter.charAt(index);
        for (Character c : _children.keySet()) {
            if (c.equals(current)) _children.get(c).retrieve(filter, index + 1, result);
            else _children.get(c).retrieve(filter, index, result);
        }
    }

    if (index >= filter.length()) {
        if (_payload != null) result.add(_payload);
        for (TrieNode n : _children.values()) n.retrieve(filter, index, result);
    }
}
```

Как это все тестировать

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TrieNode root = new TrieNode();
    root.add("Green Apple");
    root.add("Bla bla bla");
    root.add("StackOverflow");

    ShowSearchResultFor(root, "gra");
    ShowSearchResultFor(root, "gap");
    ShowSearchResultFor(root, "sof");
    ShowSearchResultFor(root, "bbb");
    ShowSearchResultFor(root, "a");
}

private static void ShowSearchResultFor(TrieNode root, String filter){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("results for: " + filter);
    for(String ret : root.retrieve(filter)){
        System.out.println(ret);
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль ожидаем

```
results for: gra
Green Apple

results for: gap
Green Apple

results for: sof
StackOverflow

results for: bbb
Bla bla bla

results for: a
Bla bla bla
StackOverflow
Green Apple
```

Answer (score 1):

Более лаконичный, но вероятно (не проверял) более медленнный подход

```
private static void ShowSearchResultFor(String[] words, String filter){
    filter = filter.toLowerCase();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("results for: " + filter);

    for(String w : words){
        int ind = 0;
        for(Character cw : w.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
            if (cw.equals(filter.charAt(ind))) ind++;
            if (ind >= filter.length()){
                System.out.println(w);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

как проверить

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = new String[3];

    words[0] = "Green Apple";
    words[1] = "Bla bla bla";
    words[2] = "StackOverflow";

    ShowSearchResultFor(words, "gra");
    ShowSearchResultFor(words, "gap");
    ShowSearchResultFor(words, "sof");
    ShowSearchResultFor(words, "bbb");
    ShowSearchResultFor(words, "a");
    ShowSearchResultFor(words, "StackOverflow");
}
```

Вывод

```
results for: gra
Green Apple

results for: gap
Green Apple

results for: sof
StackOverflow

results for: bbb
Bla bla bla

results for: a
Green Apple
Bla bla bla
StackOverflow

results for: stackoverflow
StackOverflow
```

Answer (score 1):

Вангую, что самый медленный способ с регулярками

```
private static void ShowSearchResultFor(String[] words, String filter){
    filter = filter.toLowerCase();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("results for: " + filter);

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for(Character c : filter.toCharArray()){
        buffer.append(c);
        buffer.append(".*");
    }

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(buffer.toString());
    for(String w : words){
        Matcher m = p.matcher(w.toLowerCase());
        if (m.find()) System.out.println(w);
    }
}
```

Как проверить

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = new String[3];

    words[0] = "Green Apple";
    words[1] = "Bla bla bla";
    words[2] = "StackOverflow";

    ShowSearchResultFor(words, "gra");
    ShowSearchResultFor(words, "gap");
    ShowSearchResultFor(words, "sof");
    ShowSearchResultFor(words, "bbb");
    ShowSearchResultFor(words, "a");
    ShowSearchResultFor(words, "StackOverflow");
}
```

Вывод

```
results for: gra
Green Apple

results for: gap
Green Apple

results for: sof
StackOverflow

results for: bbb
Bla bla bla

results for: a
Green Apple
Bla bla bla
StackOverflow

results for: stackoverflow
StackOverflow
```